# awk extract of a series of lines

Tags: awk

I am stuck at getting a right solution using awk to extract versions between "[]" from

```
Version    Repository  Repository URL
[1.0.0.44] repo-0     file://test/test-1.0.0.44-features.xml
[1.0.0.21] repo-0     file://test/test-1.0.0.21-features.xml
```

Is there any quick efficient one-liners anyone can help with please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk, using square brackets as the field separators, output field 2 except for record number 1:

```
awk -F '[][]' 'NR > 1 {print $2}'
```

Or, grep with `-o` is useful for extracting substrings

```
grep -oP '(?<=\[)[^]]+'
```

Comment: Genius. Works like a charm! :)